# could not for present impossibility

Tags: grammar, could

Are the following sentences with "could not" correct? I want "could not" to mean impossibility.

Peter could not be in the garden now.

Peter could not be working in the garden now.

Peter could not attend the school. The school is closed now.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are other ways to word those, but they're reasonably valid uses.

Comment: @HotLicks Some native speakers say I should use "can't" instead of "could not". What do you think?

Comment: It's a matter of emphasis/tone.

Comment: They all sound fine. The test would be to add "possibly" to each and see if it is believable. Peter could not possibly be in the garden. He could not possibly attend the school.